# Proper way to implement ABC SubClass

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class

I have an Interface class which defines the requirements to an active "in-use" class:

```
class Portfolio(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def update_portfolio(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @abstractmethod
    def update_from_fill(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @abstractmethod
    def check_signal(self, signal_event):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

The methods update_portfolio and update_from_fill are both methods which will be the same in 99% of the required cases. Only the check_signal method will vary. Therefore, to avoid having to write the same code again and again, I have defined a base class with default methods for update_portfolio and update_from_fill:

```
class BaseBacktestPortfolio(Portfolio):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...

    def update_portfolio(self, ...):
        ...

    def update_from_fill(self, ...):
        ...
```

Then, finally, I have a class inheriting from the BacktestPortfolio class which specifies the correct implementation of the check_signal method:

```
class USBacktestPortfolio(BaseBacktestPortfolio):
    def check_signal(self, ...):
        ...
```

Now, the problem is that my editor complains about the BacktestPortfolio classing not having all the required abstract methods. I could ignore this, of course, but the perfect scenario would be if I could make sure that it is not possible to instantiate an object form the BacktestPortfolio class.

Is this possible? And/or is there a more correct way to implement a structure like this?

Comment: Have you tried instantiating ``BaseBacktestPortfolio``? It already is an ABC via inheritance, which should prevent instantiating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the `BaseBacktestPortfolio` also as Abstract class.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Portfolio(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def update_portfolio(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def update_from_fill(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def check_signal(self, signal_event):
        pass

class BaseBacktestPortfolio(Portfolio, ABC):

    def update_portfolio(self):
        print("updated portfolio")

    def update_from_fill(self):
        print("update from fill")

    @abstractmethod
    def check_signal(self):
        pass

class USBacktestPortfolio(BaseBacktestPortfolio):
    def check_signal(self):
        print("checked signal")
```

Also notice that you don't need `raise NotImplementedError` inside abstract method. You can just `pass`. Its more Pythonic :)

Comment: ``BaseBacktestPortfolio`` already is an ``ABC`` by virtue of inheriting from ``Portfolio``. Adding ``ABC`` as an explicit base does not change the mro at all.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yeah, I guess you are right. I haven't tried this code without explicitly specifying it as `ABC`. But I have a doubt. By this logic, aren't _all_ the child classes of `ABC` are abstract. We don't want this in most of the cases.

Comment: Yes, any ABC subclass is abstract unless it implements the entire interface. This is often desirable when defining interfaces. For example, the ``MutableSet`` inherits from ``Set`` but defines the abstract methods ``add`` and ``discard`` in addition.

Answer (score 1):

> I could ignore this, of course, but the perfect scenario would be if I could make sure that it is not possible to instantiate an object from the BacktestPortfolio class.

That is the case in your example already:

```
>>> BaseBacktestPortfolio.mro()
[__main__.BaseBacktestPortfolio, __main__.Portfolio, abc.ABC, object]
>>> BaseBacktestPortfolio()
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class BaseBacktestPortfolio with abstract methods check_signal
```

Since `ABC` and `ABCMeta` are just regular types, their features are inherited. This includes their guards against instantiating incomplete classes. Your `BaseBacktestPortfolio` already *is* an abstract class.

The warning from your IDE/linter/... exists specifically to warn you that instantiating `BaseBacktestPortfolio` is not possible.