# Python inheritance structure and arguments

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I am trying to design a class structure that allows the user to define their own class that overloads predefined methods in other classes. In this case the user would create the C class to overload the "function" method in D. The user created C class has common logic for other user created classes A and B so they inherit from C to overload "function" but also inherit from D to use D's other methods. The issue I am having is how to pass "value" from A and B  to D and ignore passing it to C. What I currently have written will produce an error as C does not have "value" as an argument.

I know that I can add "value" (or *args) to C's init method and the super call but I don't want to have to know what inputs other classes need in order to add new classes to A and B. Also, if I swap the order of C and D I won't get an error but then I don't use C's overloaded "function". Is there an obvious way around this?

```
class D(SomethingElse):
    def __init__(self, value, **kwargs):
        super(D, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.value = value

    def function(self):
        return self.value

    def other_method(self):
        pass

class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(C, self).__init__()

    def function(self):
        return self.value*2

class B(C, D):
    def __init__(self, value, **kwargs):
        super(B, self).__init__(value, **kwargs)

class A(C, D):
    def __init__(self, value, **kwargs):
        super(A, self).__init__(value, **kwargs)



a = A(3)
print(a.function())
>>> 6
```

Comment: What should the output be?

Comment: I should be 6. I edited the post to reflect this.

Comment: It seems python2? It got different error. I got an error in `class A` on line `super(A, self).__init__(value, **kwargs)`, `__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` because `super(A, self)` tries to refer `class C` and its `__init__` doesn't recieve any positional arguments. I had to add `*args, **kwargs` to mehtioned `__init__` and write `super(C, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` and everything worked. It was python3.6.

Comment: I'm aware it doesn't work. That is what I posted this. I am also aware adding *ags fixes this. I'm just wondering if there is away around adding these. C is self contained and is only overloading methods it doesn't need to know what the input arguments are. I'm wondering if there is a way to code this without needing args and kwargs.

Comment: There's method resolution order (MRO). When function is missing, python tries to search it somewhere else (in base class, its base class and so on). When you write `super(YourClass, self)` you refer to the next class in MRO. You can write `print(A.__mro__)` youll get `[A, C, D, SomethingElse, object]`. So that, `class C` should be aware of arguments `class D` should recieve. The most convenient way is using `*args, **kwargs`. Read, please, this https://realpython.com/lessons/multiple-inheritance-python/, may contain more details.

Comment: Whern you write `super(C, self).__init__()` you're actually calling `__init__` in `D`, but it requires `value`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't pay enough attention reading your post. So, if you're finding the obvious to workaround - I say there's no way, because of implementation details posted above. Multiple inheritance isn't simple thing. C++ programmers try to avoid it at any cost, why python programmers should be different.

Comment: well darn. Thanks for the information. If I know what the resolution order is is there a way to explicitly call each class to inherit in a given order? This way I could specify which arguments each takes. i.e. something along the lines of C.__init__(self), D.__init__(self, value)

Comment: I don't know your constraints and actual result you wanna achieve. I suspect there's another way. The things you try is magic, I mean it's very unclear for everyone gonna read your code (even yourself month later).

Comment: @ChrisUchytil If class `C` is being used as a pure mixin (i.e. only providing methods), you can remove its `__init__` and your example will then work as expected.

Comment: (related but unrelated) @ChrisUchytil Mentioning it in case you haven't taken a look at it yet: worth checking out the `abc` module; [Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html). You might find use for it. ([example code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50874130/1305461))

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, there are two things you need to do to make your `__init__` methods play nice with multiple inheritance in Python:

1. Always take a `**kwargs` parameter, and always call `super().__init__(**kwargs)`, [even if you think you are the base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59832892/what-does-it-mean-when-a-parent-class-has-a-super/59833056#59833056). Just because your superclass is `object` doesn't mean you are last (before `object`) in the [method resolution order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).
2. Don't pass your parent class's `__init__` arguments explicitly; [only pass them via `**kwargs`](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/). Your parent class isn't necessarily the next one after you in the method resolution order, so positional arguments might be passed to the wrong other `__init__` method.

This is called "co-operative subclassing". Let's try with your example code:

```py
class D:
    def __init__(self, value, **kwargs):
        self.value = value
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    
    def function(self):
        return self.value

class C:
    # add **kwargs parameter
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # pass kwargs to super().__init__
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    
    def function(self):
        return self.value * 2

class B(C, D):
    # don't take parent class's value arg explicitly
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # pass value arg via kwargs
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class A(C, D):
    # don't take parent class's value arg explicitly
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # pass value arg via kwargs
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Demo:

```py
>>> a = A(value=3)
>>> a.value
3
>>> a.function()
6
```

Note that `value` must be passed to the `A` constructor as a keyword argument, not as a positional argument. It's also recommended to set `self.value = value` before calling `super().__init__`.

I've also simplified `class C(object):` to `class C:`, and `super(C, self)` to just `super()` since these are equivalent in Python 3.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is how to **totally avoid** changing the signature of `C.__init__` whilst using still `super`.

Comment: @ekhumoro I don't see any part of the question which says or implies that the signature of `C.__init__` can't be changed. I'm not sure how you got that from the question; please explain.

Comment: 1st sentence of the 2nd paragraph (and the comments, where `*args, **kwargs` etc has already been discussed).

Comment: *"I don't want to have to know what inputs other classes need in order to add new classes to A and B"* Is this the part you mean? It doesn't say the signature can't be changed, only that `C.__init__` should not be coupled to the signatures of the other `__init__` methods; and using `kwargs` means it's not. `C` doesn't know or care what's in `kwargs`.

Comment: If you read the comments as well, and you'll see that the OP wants to avoid having `**kwargs` as a requirement:  "I'm wondering if there is a way to code this without needing args and kwargs".

Answer (score 0):

So I'm trying to understand the point of A AND B.  I'm guessing that maybe you want to mix in the superclass behavior and sometimes have local behavior.  So suppose A is just mixing together behaviors, and B has some local behavior and state.

If you don't need your own state, you probably don't need an `__init__`.  So for `A` and `C` just omit `__init__`.

```
class SomethingElse(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

class D(SomethingElse):
    def __init__(self, value, *args,  **kwargs):
        super(D, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.value = value

    def function(self):
        return self.value

    def other_method(self):
        return self.__dict__

class C(object):
    #def __init__(self):
    #    super(C, self).__init__()

    def function(self):
        return self.value*2

class B(C, D):
    def __init__(self, value, bstate, *args, **kwargs):
        super(B, self).__init__(value, *args, **kwargs)
        self.bstate = bstate

    def __repr__(self):
        return (self.__class__.__name__ + ' ' +
                self.bstate + ' ' + str(self.other_method()))

class A(C, D):
    pass


a = A(3)
b = B(21, 'extra')

a.function()
6

b.function()
42
repr(a)
'<xx.A object at 0x107cf5e10>'
repr(b)
"B extra {'args': (), 'bstate': 'extra', 'value': 21, 'kwargs': {}}"
```

I've kept python2 syntax assuming you might still be using it, but as another answer points out, python3 simplifies `super()` syntax, and you really should be using python3 now.

If you swap C and D you are changing the python method resolution order, and that will indeed change the method to which a call to A.function resolves.